# What does Array.prototype.slice.call() & wrapper.querySelectorAll() do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, selectors-api

I found following cone in a js plugin

```
var container = document.getElementById( 'vs-container' ),
wrapper = container.querySelector( 'div.vs-wrapper' ),
sections = Array.prototype.slice.call( wrapper.querySelectorAll( 'section' ) ),
links = Array.prototype.slice.call( container.querySelectorAll( 'header.vs-header > ul.vs-nav > li' ) );
```

I couldn't understand what does `Array.prototype.slice.call()` & `wrapper.querySelectorAll( 'section' )` do in above code. I've not seen them before so I would like to know what they actually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` is a method on DOM elements that accepts a CSS selector and returns a static `NodeList` of matching elements.

`Array.prototype.slice.call` is one way to turn that `NodeList` (which acts like an array, but doesn’t have the methods from `Array.prototype`) into a real array.

Give it a try on this page in your browser’s console!

```
> var headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
undefined
> headers.map(function(el) { return el.textContent; })
TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'map'
> headers = Array.prototype.slice.call(headers);
…
> headers.map(function(el) { return el.textContent; })
["What does Array.prototype.slice.call() & wrapper.querySelectorAll() do?", …]
```

Answer (score 2):

It creates an array from anything array-like (e.g., that has a `length` and properties with names like `0`, `1`, etc.). You see it a lot with `getElementsByTagName` and such, which return live `NodeList` instances. It's not really necessary with `querySelectorAll`, because that returns non-live lists, unless of course you want all the features of `Array`.

That `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)` can look a bit intimidating, but it's actually quite simple: Arrays get their methods from the object `Array.prototype`. One of those is the `slice` method that returns a copy of a portion of the array. If you don't give `slice` any arguments, it returns a copy of the entire array. But the tricky bit is that when you call `slice`, you don't have to call it on an array, just something that looks array-like. When you use `Function#call` in JavaScript, you can set what `this` is within the call. So `Array.prototype.slice.call(resultFromQuerySelectorAll)` calls `slice` with `this` being the result from `querySelectorAll`; `slice` then obligingly gives you an array with those entries.