# jQuery - check if element(s) exists without selecting all elements

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to simply check if an element exists, rather than the horribly inefficient method of selecting the elements and checking the `.length` of the result? It seems jQuery could easily include a function that returns true if it finds a matched element.

Comment: Nope, for jquery to be able to return true it would still have to select them all. You could of course make up your own plugin that checks the length and returns true, but that seems kinda pointless.

Comment: Thanks. It's really confusing why they wouldn't include something such as that.

Comment: What you are suggesting is looping over every element in the DOM and stopping if and when you find a match.  That's actually *slower* than using a selector to find element(s).  The selectors can use built in `getElementsByXXX` methods (or sizzle, jQuery's selector engine) and that's actually pretty quick.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't solve any cross-browser issues or provide any performance benefits.

Comment: Also, even if jQuery has to select the elements, it could still know if there's at least one element and not build the returned array, simply return true. It would cut down on processing.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, that makes much more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Kevin B, if you're checking the existence of a potentially large result set, it would definitely provide a performance benefit by discarding the array containing (potentially) hundreds or thousands of jQuery objects and only returning true/false. Although in that case it would be easy enough to create a boolean designating the existence.

Comment: prove it, this has been tried before. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11785 I know that isn't exactly the same, but it's going by the same concept.

Comment: You just use `querySelector('selector')` and it will stop as soon as it finds the first match.

Comment: Here's another relevant ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3842

Comment: Kevin B, in the test they created (http://jsperf.com/findone-vs-findall) their findOne function is definitely faster. Not by a huge amount, but faster nonetheless. And that's not even using a large number of elements.

Comment: dfsq, thanks. That's a good solution. Looks like the browser support is pretty good also: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: in that perf, why is he creating a copy of the returned collection in the findAll method?

Comment: That's a good point. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099170/what-does-array-prototype-slice-call-wrapper-queryselectorall-do It's so it returns an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you used `:has` selector

```
$( "div:has(p)" )
```

[**Reference link**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I am pretty sure that the advanced selectors like `:has` are jQuery selectors and are not iterated natively by the browser. This means that they are iterated in JS by jQuery making them incredibly inefficient.

Comment: To add to my previous comment.. `$('div>p').has('#myP')` would be way faster. However your code could just be rewitten as `$('div>p).length > 0` and would still be faster.