# MDN example of Call on an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

guys i am trying to understand why call really works , i am new to object oriented java script , the this keyword and functions like call .

I found the below line in a programme online :

```
this.tabs = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'nav > ul > li' );
```

i tried understanding each function and was quite successful , actually the below thread helped me :

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099170/what-does-array-prototype-slice-call-wrapper-queryselectorall-do)

but then understanding call is a bit difficult , espically after looking [MDN call doc's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

i don't quite understand this example in the MDN docs:

USING CALL TO INVOKE AN ANONYMOUS FUNCTION :

```
var animals = [
  { species: 'Lion', name: 'King' },
  { species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    this.print = function() {
      console.log('#' + i + ' ' + this.species
                  + ': ' + this.name);
    }
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}
```

Now i understand the Object literal , i understand the for loop , I understand the IIFE , i understand the this.print(); function being called ,

What i don't understand though is the below line :

```
call(animals[i], i);
```

and the parameters being passed into it .

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(function () { ... }).call(animals[i], i)` calls the function `(function () { ... })` "on" the object `animals[i]` (that is: within the scope of the call, `this` will be `animals[i]`), with the argument `i`.

In other words, it's equivalent to this:

```
animals[i].f = function () { ... };
animals[i].f(i);
```

except without having to set `animals[i].f`.

Comment: so inside (function(i) { }) , this will point to animals[i] ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler way to explain it is to collapse it down a bit:

```
 (function(i) {
    this.print = function() {
      console.log('#' + i + ' ' + this.species
                  + ': ' + this.name);
    }
    this.print();
  }).call(animals[i], i);
```

to

```
(function(i) {...}).call(animals[i], i);
```

The call could be mistakenly thought to being applied to the animals[i], but it is actually being applied to the anonymous function that has been defined.  In other words, the "call" method is being invoked on the anonymous function that was just created.  In this way the function is applied to the animals without defining it explicitly.

Comment: so inside (function(i) { }) , this will point to animals[i] ?

Comment: Exactly!  I think you've got it. :)  Welcome to the world of "lambda closures" as we call them in some other languages.  Don't worry, they are very confusing. :)